# Yii2 search link

Tags: php, forms, search, hyperlink, yii2

In Yii2 I have search link like this: `localhost/project/web/?ItemSearch%5Btitle%5D=star`

How can I change it to: `localhost/project/web/?title=star`?

This is my form

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'title') ?>
```

and it looks like this

```
<input type="text" name="ItemSearch[title]">
```

when I tried to change it to:

```
<input type="text" name="title">
```

search doesn't work but link looks good.

Do you have any idea how to make it?

Comment: are you working with the `GridView` search form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to override the `formName` method of your model to return an empty string
essentially it will skip the model name from the `name` property of your inputs (all inputs where you use this model)

```
class ItemSearch extends Model
{
    public function formName() {
        return '';
    }
}
```